# Version-control of specific files on Git

Tags: git, version-control, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git - Whitelisting files in a complex directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/git-whitelisting-files-in-a-complex-directory-structure)

I have a project called [Basic PHP Framework - *alpha*](https://github.com/david-proweb/basic) and it have some files on root dir.

When I need to apply the FW in some project, I just need to use dirs *basic* (or file *basic.phar*), *application* and files *index.php* and *.htaccess*. All other files are for debug purposes.

Here start the *"good thing"*: I want work on projects based on this FW with Git version-control, because sometimes I need do a emergency change on this files and, currently, I need EVERYTIME copy manually to project dir (`/basic`) and sync. It's so annoying. The same if I need update project using git.

My idea is something like sync GIT using specific directories and ignoring all others that not interest me, on each project.

It's possible, currently?

*I'm new here, and I don't know if here is the right place to post this kind of question. Feel free to move to another "stack-place".*

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9162919/321973 (I know it's newer, but the answer there is actually correct"er")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a [`.gitignore` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) in the project directory to blacklist/whitelist any file you don't want git to bother tracker, e.g.:

```sh
*
# ignore every file by default
!.htaccess
# but don't ignore .htaccess
!basic
!basic/*
!basic/*/*
# don't ignore the 'basic' directory (and 2 levels below)
!index.php
# etc.
```

(It's easier to setup a blacklist if "All other files for debug purposes" have some common pattern.)

Comment: You may have to whitelist `!*/` as well if you got a nested structure, as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227991/321973)