# How to let gitignore track subdirectory instances of a file while ignoring everything else?

Tags: git, gitignore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git - Whitelisting files in a complex directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/git-whitelisting-files-in-a-complex-directory-structure)

I'd like to have a git repository track only files named e.g. `SOURCES` while everything else shall be ignored (take e.g. a tree of pdf files where each `SOURCES` file lists their origins). The simplest shot would have been

```
*
!SOURCES
```

in `.gitignore`. However the exclusion of e.g. `A/SOURCES` is overridden by the `*`, requiring me to use `git add -f`. How can `.gitignore` be modified to ignore everything except files named `SOURCES` without requiring a forced add?

**edit** The solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248601/321973) will not do since the directory structure is not fixed, i.e. new directories containing a `SOURCES` file should not have to be added to `.gitignore` by hand...

Comment: basically also a duplicate of [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/987142/321973), but that doesn't have the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this using just `.gitignore`

Git doesn't track paths. It tracks objects (~ files) only.

So, why don't you reverse the tables:

```
git add -f -- */*/SOURCES */SOURCES
```

or

```
shopt -s globstar
git add -f -- **/SOURCES
```

Or get out the big guns:

```
git add -f -- $(find -type f -name SOURCES)
```

or even

```
find -type f -name SOURCES -exec git add -f -- {} \+
```

**Untested idea** Perhaps something like this could be in a pre-commit hook?

---

**Update** An idea for more automation:

Add this to .git/config

```
[alias]
ac = "!_() { git add -f -- */*/SOURCES && git commit \"$@\"; }; _"
```

Now, you can just say

```
git commit -m 'like you usually work'
```

and it will automatically add the `*/*/SOURCES`

Comment: This will still ignore `A/SOURCES`. Should the order of entries actually matter?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler you are right. I kind-a misread the question. _And_ the order does not matter. Edited

Comment: My bad for not being more precise about that... Interesting, I didn't see the connection to git not tracking paths. Well, if I have to use `git add -f` anyway, `.gitignore` can simply contain `*`... I was hoping that `git status` would remind me that I added a new `SOURCES` file somewhere. I could do something really bad/evil/stupid and use a clean/smudge-filter to simply store empty objects for everything that is not a `SOURCES` file...

Comment: Hm, _if_ I restrict myself to one single level of nesting, the entries `*/*` and `!*/SOURCES` do the trick. However no combination of different depths seems possible...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I added a bonus sketch using git alias so you can have the `-f` additions automated. In case you like it

Comment: Thanks. Oh, now thanks to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files#comment11620636_987162) to a related question I realized that `*`, `!*/`, `!SOURCES` actually _does_ work. Making this question a duplicate of [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9162919/321973) though... And: You were actually right, the order in `.gitignore` does matter. Just compare `*`, `!.gitignore` to `!.gitignore`, `*`. Exceptions should apparently be listed last.