# gitignore all files in all subdirectories except xml files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory structure similar to this:

```
root/
  .gitignore
  subdir/
    .gitignore
    subsubdir1/
      file.xml
      image.png
    subsubdir2
       file.xml
       image.jpg
```

I want to ignore all files from `subdir` except XML files.
the second `.gitignore` looks like this:

```
*                   # ignore everything in this directory and its subdirectories
!*/                 # do not ignore subdirectories
!*.xml              # do not ignore xml files
!.gitignore         # and of course have this .gitignore file included too
```

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/git-whitelisting-files-in-a-complex-directory-structure) and various other posts here on SO and other sites, this should work just fine, but for some reason `git status` shows me that all the files in `subdir` folder are untracked.

I have used `git rm --cached` to remove all files that have been tracked before `.gitignore` was added, but that still did not do the trick.

Do you have any clue, what would fix this ?

P.S.:
In case it matters I am using git on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.gitignore does not support inline comments.   Comments need to start on their own line.

---

You need to remove the !*/  this will end up undoing the line before it.

If you want to ignore everything in subdir but not in subsubdirs then that line should be:

```
!/*
```

If you want to ignore files like subdir/subsubdir2/image.jpg then you can just leave that line out.

Empty directories (or where all files inside are ignored) won't be added to git.

I think (and confirmed on my linux system) that .gitignore is automatically excluded so you can omit the last line.

This leaves in subdir/.gitignore:

```
*
!*.xml
```

Comment: I don't know there is something fundamentally broken with my repository, because now I tried to leave only the first rule in my gitignore (i.e. only the star) and it just completely disregards me (I am doing `git status` and all the changes from the root directory if that matters somehow ...)

Comment: If you changed your root/.gitignore the !*/ in subdir/.gitignore would still override it.

Comment: no I have changed the `.gitignore` from `subdir` folder, but while fixing this problem I have done several times `git reset HEAD` (yet before posting here). I don't know if that changes anything, I am already trying anything possible as I have no idea, why this is happening

Comment: OK, so the directories in my example had just stub names to demonstrate my problems.
Here is the actual structure of `subdir` folder: [link](http://pastebin.com/DwE6qfuv)
Here is the `git status` output: [link](http://pastebin.com/fYwaXP0C)
Here is the first `.gitignore`: [link](http://pastebin.com/21fwr7hA)
And here is the second one: [link](http://pastebin.com/VuGLK9mC)

Comment: Oh, I see now. 
.gitignore does not support inline comments.  Comments have to start on their own line.

Comment: Yes, Thanks! I have just realised that too, after posting all those files. Please put that in your answer and I will mark it as accepted.