# Gitignore double star pattern does not work

Tags: git, bash, file, gitignore

I am trying to exclude all files except those I need with the following `.gitignore` config:

```
*.* # Ignore all files
*~  # Ignore temp files
\#* # Ignore temp files

!.gitignore
!*.conf
!**/*.conf
```

However, file `./postgresql/9.3/warm-standby/postgresql.conf` is not shown when I execute `git status`. How can I fix my `.gitignore`?

Git version is 2.1.4

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/whitelisting-and-subdirectories-in-git

Answer (score 4):

First of all: *credit to @EtanReisner for carefully looking into this and @RetoAebersold for providing the correct [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/whitelisting-and-subdirectories-in-git)*

The problem is that with the following statement (not part of *your* `.gitignore`), you blacklist both files and **directories**:

```
*
```

Now if you use `*.*` like you did, that's normally not a problem, because most directories don't contain a dot (`.`). Yours however does:

```
*           .*
postgresql/9.3
```

So what happens is that all directories are blacklisted. In order to enable adding files in directories, **you first need to whitelist these directories**. You can do this with the oneliner:

```
!*.*/
```

In other words, whitelist everything that ends with a slash.

And now you can whitelist the files as well:

```
!*.conf
```

Note that whitelisting `!**/*.conf` is not necessary (It is probably not even allowed, especially since two consecutive asterisks `**` were only enabled in git 1.8.*).

A better configuration file thus reads:

```
*.* # Ignore all files
*~  # Ignore temp files
\#* # Ignore temp files
!*/
!*.*/

!.gitignore
!*.conf
```

Comment: Those suggestions work if I add `**/*` to my `.gitignore`, `*.*` seems to exclude only files that are in the current directory. It would be nice to update the answer

Comment: Normally `*.*` will disable *all* files/directories with a dot. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I have lots of files that need to be excluded in subdirectories. `*.*` seems not to exclude them, so `**/*` or `**/*.*` is needed for it to work recursively.