# creating branch for gh pages from a particular folder, to check in only files

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I've java project which generates html files in directory path main_project/target/cucumber_output/

I need to check in only these html files and nothing more. But when I create gh-pages branch on main_project it does check-in target/cucumber_output folders as well.

I need to check in only all the files under cucumber_out, how to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://srackham.wordpress.com/2014/12/14/publishing-a-project-website-to-github-pages/

This explains requirement I would like to implement.

Also I have referred to unignore a subdirectory as per

[.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `.gitignore` file and add all files except `cucumber_output` folder. Your `.gitignore` file should looks like:

```
/*
!main_project/target/cucumber_output
!.gitignore
```

> An optional prefix ! which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. If a negated pattern matches, this will override lower precedence patterns sources.

Possibly duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/987142/4133798) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9162919/4133798) !